# How to cut from multiple input videos and concat to single video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I did something like this

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:03:00 -i video2.mp4 -ss 00:05:00 -to 00:02:00 -c copy cut.mp4
```

Apparently muxing didnt happen.

How can I make it work?

Comment: This appears to be off-topic as it is not directly related to programming.

Comment: Actually I am wrapping it in a .Net class but I need the correct command line argument.

Answer (score 6):

You have to tell `ffmpeg` that you want to concatenate each video and audio stream:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex
"[0:v]trim=start=60:end=180,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
 [0:a]atrim=start=60:end=180,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];
 [1:v]trim=start=300:end=420,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];
 [1:a]atrim=start=300:end=420,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];
 [v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

- `(a)trim` creates each segment, `(a)setpts` resets the segment timestamps (recommended for `concat`), and `concat` concatenates each segment. See [FFmpeg Filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) for documentation on each filter.
- I broke up the command into separate lines for readability. Reconstitute into a single line or add whatever line-break characters are suitable for your environment.
- This will re-encode the video but cutting will be accurate. If you want to avoid re-encoding see the [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer) but cutting may not be accurate and results may not be satisfactory.
- The `-to` value cannot be smaller than the `-ss` value, so I'm going to assume you meant `-ss 00:05:00 -to 00:07:00` instead of `-ss 00:05:00 -to 00:02:00`.